# Implementation of multiple sink shortest pair of disjoint paths problem for multigraphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I would like to implement the shortest pairs of edge-disjoint paths of Suurballe and Tarjan for **multigraphs** in the interpretation of Banerjee *et al.* (http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~pavan/papers/short.pdf, relying only on Section 3).

As regards **simple graphs**, this algorithm can be defined for a *G=(V,E)* simple graph having a source *s* and nonnegative edge costs *c(u,v)* as follows:

(1) Construct the shortest path tree *T* rooted at *s* for *G* using the Dijkstra algorithm.

(2) Reduce the cost on all edges *(a,b)* as *c'(a,b)=c(a,b)+d(a)-d(b)*, where *d(a)* is the distance of vertex *a* from vertex *s*.

(3) Create an auxiliary graph *G'=(V',E')* in the following way:

(3.1) set *V'=V* and *E'* = empty,

(3.2) for each nontree edge (a,b) of *E\T*:

(3.2.1) define *V* * as the set of nodes in the path between *a* and *b* in *T* except for *b*,

(3.2.2) for each *v'* of *V* *: set *E'=E' U {(v',b)}* and *c'(v',b)=c'(a,b)*.

(4) Construct a shortest path tree *T'* rooted at *s* for *G'* weighted by the *c'* function, using the Dijkstra algorithm.

(5) Save the predecessor of each vertex *x* in *T'* as *q(x)* and the tail of the nontree edge in *G* which caused the insertion of the *(q(x),x)* in *G'*.

(6) Create the pairs of edge-disjoint paths for each *v* of *V* in the following manner:

(6.1) Mark all the vertices in the shortest path from *v* to *s* in *G*.

(6.2) Generate the paths by two iterations of the step *Traversal* given below. In each iteration one path of the shortest pairs is generated.

*Traversal:* Define *x=v*, the path to be empty and repeat the following steps until *x=s*. If *x* is marked then unmark it and add *(p(x),x)* to the path, or else add *(y,x)* to the path, where *y* is the parent of *x* in *T*.

Could you please help me how to reformulate the algorithm for multigraphs? I guess that G', p(), q(), and *Traversal* of Section 3 in paper of Banerjee *et al.* should be modified somehow, but I don't know how.

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on the [computer science stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), you might get more answers than here.